# Can't bind to 'paint' since it isn't a known property of 'mgl-layer' with mapbox in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mapbox-gl-js

I have angular 9 + I am using the latest mapbox version.

So I want to toggle some data: countours and museums in this case.

So I have installed the package:  "@types/mapbox-gl": "^1.12.5",

and I included in app.module.ts like this:

```
 NgxMapboxGLModule.withConfig({
      accessToken:
        'pk.ljljlkjnA5ZzAyYnVtaGkifQ.LfTgQzPszKiyVQjKiUFsyg', // accessToken can also be set per map (accessToken input of mgl-map)
    }),
```

and I have a component like this:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <mgl-map
      style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
      [zoom]="[15]"
      [center]="[-71.97722138410576, -13.517379300798098]"
    >
      <mgl-vector-source id="museums" url="mapbox://mapbox.2opop9hr"> </mgl-vector-source>
      <mgl-vector-source id="contours" url="mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2"> </mgl-vector-source>
      <mgl-layer
        id="museums"
        type="circle"
        source="museums"
        [layout]="layouts.museums"
        [paint]="{
          'circle-radius': 8,
          'circle-color': 'rgba(55,148,179,1)'
        }"
        sourceLayer="museum-cusco"
      >
      </mgl-layer>
      <mgl-layer
        id="contours"
        type="line"
        source="contours"
        [layout]="layouts.contours"
        [paint]="{
          'line-color': '#877b59',
          'line-width': 1
        }"
        sourceLayer="contour"
      >
      </mgl-layer>
    </mgl-map>
    <div class="menu">
     <!--  <mat-button-toggle [checked]="true" value="contours" (change)="toggleLayer($event)"
        >contours</mat-button-toggle
      >
      <mat-button-toggle [checked]="true" value="museums" (change)="toggleLayer($event)"
        >museums</mat-button-toggle -->
      >
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./toggle-layer.component.scss'],
})
export class ToggleLayersComponent implements OnInit {
  layouts = {
    contours: {
      visibility: 'visible',
      'line-join': 'round',
      'line-cap': 'round',
    },
    museums: {
      visibility: 'visible',
    },
  };

  ngOnInit() {}

  toggleLayer(evt: {value: 'contours' | 'museums'}) {
    const key = evt.value as 'contours';

    this.layouts[key] = {
      ...this.layouts[key],
      visibility: this.layouts[key].visibility === 'visible' ? 'none' : 'visible',
    };
  }
}
```

But I get this errors:

```
    1. If 'mgl-layer' is an Angular component and it has 'paint' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mgl-layer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

    29         [paint]="{
      m         ~~~~~~~~~~
    30           'line-color': '#877b59',
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    31           'line-width': 1
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    32         }"
```

So what I have to change?

But the intellisens find for example: [layout]...
and also if I stand on [layout] and press f12 I go to the definition. But I cant build Angular.
Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <mgl-map
      style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
      [zoom]="[15]"
      [center]="[-71.97722138410576, -13.517379300798098]"
    >
      <mgl-vector-source id="museums" url="mapbox://mapbox.2opop9hr"> </mgl-vector-source>
      <mgl-vector-source id="contours" url="mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2"> </mgl-vector-source>
      <mgl-layer
        id="museums"
        type="circle"
        source="museums"
        layout="layouts.museums"
        paint="{
          'circle-radius': 8,
          'circle-color': 'rgba(55,148,179,1)'
        }"
        sourceLayer="museum-cusco"
      >
      </mgl-layer>
      <mgl-layer
        id="contours"
        type="line"
        source="contours"
        layout="layouts.contours"
        paint="{
          'line-color': '#877b59',
          'line-width': 1
        }"
        sourceLayer="contour"
      >
      </mgl-layer>
    </mgl-map>

    <div class="menu">></div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./toggle-layer.component.scss'],
})
```

this are the errors:

```
src/app/desktop-dashboard/toggle-layer/toggle-layer.component.ts:24:7 - error NG8001: 'mgl-layer' is not a known element:
1. If 'mgl-layer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mgl-layer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

 24       <mgl-layer
          ~~~~~~~~~~
 25         id="contours"
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
 33         sourceLayer="contour"
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 34       >
    ~~~~~~~
```

So in my child module I have this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DesktopDashboardComponent, BarChartComponent, TestDesktopComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    DesktopRoutingModule,
    NgxMapboxGLModule,
    /*  MatButtonToggleModule, */
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class DesktopDashboardModule {}
```

and in app.module I have this:

```
NgxMapboxGLModule.withConfig({
      accessToken:
        'pk.eyJ1IpwYjBpazAyenA5ZzAyYnVtaGkifQ.LfTgQzPszKiyVQjKiUFsyg', // accessToken can also be set per map (accessToken input of mgl-map)
    }),
```

ah, oke, I did this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DesktopDashboardComponent, BarChartComponent, TestDesktopComponent, ToggleLayersComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    DesktopRoutingModule,
    NgxMapboxGLModule,
    /*  MatButtonToggleModule, */
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class DesktopDashboardModule {}
```

And I dont get any errors. But also nothing is showing

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind `paint` to a local variable but you are actually providing an inline object literal. You either have to create a public property in your component, e.g.:

```js
// toggle-layer.component.ts
public paintConfig = {
  'circle-radius': 8,
  'circle-color': 'rgba(55,148,179,1)'
}
```

```html
// HTML template
<mgl-layer
  ...
  [paint]="paintConfig"
>...</mgl-layer>
```

or you can remove the binding and use an object literal:

```html
<mgl-layer
  ...
  paint="{
    'line-color': '#877b59',
    'line-width': 1
  }"
>...</mgl-layer>
```

Comment: ? But then For everything?

Comment: Bug  </mgl-layer> sits in the mgl-map

Comment: This example: https://libraries.io/github/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl

Comment: All your errors are of the same type - you are binding to non-existing property by using an object/array literal - "center", "zoom" etc.

Comment: yes, oke, but in the total example I posted. What is then The total solution? Because if I just put one snippet it doesnt work

Comment: This is from the site: https://npm.io/package/@ngx-mapbox-gl/core

Comment: doesnt work:   template: `
    <mgl-map
    [style]="'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9'"
    [zoom]="[9]"
    [center]="[-74.50, 40]"
  >
  </mgl-map>

Comment: Have you correctly imported ngx-mapbox in your AppModule (or the module you're referencing it from if it is different)?

Comment: Yes, import { NgxMapboxGLModule } from 'ngx-mapbox-gl';

Comment: But I get now this error: zone-evergreen.js:171 Uncaught Error: Unable to parse URL object
    at Y (mapbox-gl.js:31)

Comment: I made a other question for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64607315/vm6371-polyfills-js184-uncaught-error-unable-to-parse-url-object-with-mapbox-i

Answer (score 0):

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DesktopDashboardComponent, BarChartComponent, TestDesktopComponent, ToggleLayersComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    DesktopRoutingModule,
    NgxMapboxGLModule,
    /*  MatButtonToggleModule, */
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class DesktopDashboardModule {}
```